# Firebase event when user is added

Tags: javascript, events, firebase

I would like to react to when a new user is added in the Firebase managed user system (from my Node app).

I don't need any other info associated with a user so it seems a waste to have to add my own user entry from the client just so the Node app knows one was added.

It also creates another point of failure - i.e. if the user is created but then my write to `users` fails I would need to rewind on the client and delete the user account so they can try again.. and if `removeUser` also fails then the logic would get nasty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for Firebase Authentication that informs you that a new user account was created.

Comment: Alright thanks, I had a hunch so started to implement it the other way. It's not too messy with Promises.